# Can I point a folder hosted on AWS, to my current hosted site in Aptible?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, wordpress, web-hosting, godaddy

I have a domain www.example.com (which is built with PHP/MySQL) hosted on Aptible server. Now, I am planning to create a blog with WordPress which will be hosted on AWS, and will be integrate to the site.

So my question is, will it be possible to integrate the WordPress blog which resides on AWS, to my site (which is hosted on Aptible?)

The end URL should look something like www.example.com/blog (which will point to AWS WordPress codebase).

P.S: The domain is registered with GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do to ensure its understood?

What I think you are trying to do is to redirect www.example.com/blog elsewhere to another server, you will struggle without a redirect to a different host e.g you could redirect traffic but the domain name in the url of the actual blog would ultimately have to be something else.

A **better route** might be to use blog.example.com and have blog.example.com hit the AWS based WordPress blog.

Comment: What I am trying to here is to load www.example.com/blog (Just this specific component) from AWS server, which has Wordpress codebase. and all other components of the site will load from Aptible server. Also, I guess "blog.example.com" is bad for SEO? and we should only use one single domain?

Comment: unless both sites are served from the same server, or a load balancer is able to redirect to a different server behind it, your only really practical solution is to use a different domain/sub domain.